# Turf.js circle polygon coordinates issue

Tags: node.js, polygon, turfjs

**Library**: http://turfjs.org/

**Platform Using**: Node.js v8.9.4

**Turf version**: latest from npm - @turf/turf

**Code:**

```
var center = [20.659698486328125, -103.349609375];
var options = { steps: 5, units: 'kilometers', options: {} };
var radius = 1;
var polygon = turf.circle(center, radius, options);
```

**Polygon I receive:**

```
[ [ [ 20.659698486328125, -76.65938382863723 ],
[ 20.663518747226156, -76.65934049531025 ],
[ 20.66730214442299, -76.65921091347738 ],
[ 20.655878225430094, -76.65934049531025 ],
[ 20.659698486328125, -76.65938382863723 ] ] ]
```

**Issue:**

Polygon coordinates are wrong, latitude is correct. however, longitude is totally different.

Tried each and everything with this library, still coordinates are wrong, creating polygon in totally different region.

Answer (score 0):

Try swapping longitude/latitude of center in the call to `turf.circle`

```js
var center_orig = [20.659698486328125, -103.349609375];
var center = [-103.349609375, 20.659698486328125];
var options = {
  steps: 5,
  units: 'kilometers',
  options: {}
};
var radius = 1;
var polygon = turf.circle(center, radius, options);

var map = L.map('mapid').setView(center_orig, 13);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);

L.geoJSON(polygon, {
  style: function(feature) {
    return {
      color: "red"
    };
  }
}).addTo(map);
```

```css
#mapid {
  height: 264px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@turf/turf@5/turf.min.js"></script>

<div id="mapid"></div>
```

Comment: can you check this Please, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55974083/attempting-to-a-configurable-attribute-of-a-configurable-property-issue-in-turfj